# Cloud Service Custom Domain Redirection configuration

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

i am not sure whether this correct words to describe the problem, but i try my best to explain.

Suppose i deployed a cloud service with A Name. now client ask me give me something good domain name rather than `A.cloudapp.net`, so according to need i given him fancy domain name `A.myapp.com`.

After some time they thinks `A` is not a good name , give me `B`. so i change the deployment to `B.cloudapp.net` and then configured custom Domain Name as `B.myapp.com`.

Client again comes as says my customer is still using `A.myapp.com`. Can you do something to redirect them to `B.myapp.com`. with message that it moved to another address.

As i know i used only `CNAME` and `ARecord` on domain registrar . how can show a message over there. That this page is moved to other domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A.myapp.com` is no longer in the DNS records then the only way that it's still working is that the DNS propagation hasn't taken full effect yet.  That can take even up to a few days.  Once that happens then `A.myapp.com` should no longer resolve.  This might also be working if you have a wildcard record for `@.myapp.com` pointing to the same `A.cloudapp.net` site.

You can create the `A.myapp.com` DNS record (if it's not still there) and point it to the same cloudapp.net app again, but then in your cloud app look at the hostname as it comes it to the request.  If it is `A.myapp.com` show them a specific page that reminds them this is now `B.myapp.com` and then redirect them.